# Why can't we pass generic type T instead of ? in generics

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

I have an Animal class and a Cat class which extends Animal (Cat is an Animal)
I have defined a generic class:

```
public class Employee<T extends Animal> {
    T obj;
    Employee(T o){
        obj=o;
    }
    String getName(Employee<T> a){
        return "ok";
    }
}
```

In a test class, if i write this, it gives me the following error error:

```
Employee<Cat> cat = new Employee<Cat>(null);
Employee<Animal> animal = new Employee<Animal>(null);
animal.getName(cat);
```

But if i give pass question mark for  getName method, it works , i thought Cat is an Animal (Cat class extends Animal) . Any idea why i need to pass ? instead of T ?

Comment: Integer does not extend Animal?

Comment: sorry, ignore the Employee<Integer> a = new Employee<Integer>(null); part

Comment: You forgot to include the error.

Comment: This is relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2745265/2891664.

Comment: @ kevin- method getName(Employee<Animal>)  in the type Employee<Animal> is not applicable for the arguments Employee<Cat>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a method `getName(Employee<T> a)` then this method only accepts `Employee<T>`, which in the case of `animal.getName(a)` means that it must be an `Employee<Animal>` (because `animal` is an `Employee<Animal>`.

If you also want to accept subclasses of the generic type, you have to say

```
String getName(Employee<? extends T> a)
```

If you also want to accept superclasses of the generic type, you have to say

```
String getName(Employee<? super T> a)
```

If you don't actually care about the generic type of the other animal, you can say

```
String getName(Employee<?> a)
```

Which of these four cases is appropriate depends on what the method actually needs to do (and how the generic type is used by the two objects and their other methods).

Answer (score 1):

Although `Cat` is compatible with `Animal`, `Employee<Cat>` is not compatible with `Employee<Animal>`. They are completely different types. Or to put it more generally, `A<T>` is not compatible with `A<U>` even if `T` is compatible with `U`.

What's the difference between `<?>` and `<T>`?

In `<T>`, you have a generic type parameter `T`, which in this case, is `Animal`. Thus, the method is accepting an argument of type `Employee<Animal>.` As I have said, putting an `Employee<Cat>` in `Employee<Animal>` just does not work, which is why the code fails to compile.

`<?>` on the other hand, allows anything to be put into the brackets, whether it is `Cat`, `Dog`, `Tiger`, `Unicorn`, whatever.

P.S. Why does `Employee` have a field of type `Animal`? That's kind of weird... just saying...

Comment: The logic in the example was bad , my bad :)